# How to store variables from a text file and manipulate its contents: Spark RDD / Scala -

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm not sure how to read the data into manageable variables or manipulate the data in order to retrieve the highest and lowest sales figures.

**Question:
Calculate the highest/lowest selling genre based on global sales (where global sales = NA_Sales + EU_Sales + JP_Sales). 
Print the result to the terminal using println.**

*Example output: 
Highest selling genre: Shooter  Global Sales: 27.57
Lowest selling genre: Strategy  Global sales: 0.23*

```
//Create a case class to to represent the 9 columns 
case class Sales (Name: String, Platform: String, Year: Int, Genre: String, Publisher: String, NA_Sales: Double, EU_Sales: Double, JP_Sales: Double, Other_Sales: Double)

//Generate a sales schema based upon our class above
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val salesSchema = Encoders.product[Sales].schema


//Using our data schema we can load the Sales data as a Dataframe
val salesDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").schema(salesSchema).csv("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/assignment/t1/vgsales-small.csv")

//convert a DataFrame to a DataSet
val salesDS = salesDF.as[Sales]
```

The database is in the following format:

```
Gran Turismo 3: A-Spec;PS2;2001;Racing;Sony Computer Entertainment;6.85;5.09;1.87;1.16
Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3;X360;2011;Shooter;Activision;9.03;4.28;0.13;1.32
Pokemon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition;GB;1998;Role-Playing;Nintendo;5.89;5.04;3.12;0.59
Call of Duty: Black Ops;X360;2010;Shooter;Activision;9.67;3.73;0.11;1.13
Pokemon HeartGold/Pokemon SoulSilver;DS;2009;Action;Nintendo;4.4;2.77;3.96;0.77
High Heat Major League Baseball 2003;PS2;2002;Sports;3DO;0.18;0.14;0;0.05
Panzer Dragoon;SAT;1995;Shooter;Sega;0;0;0.37;0
Corvette;GBA;2003;Racing;TDK Mediactive;0.2;0.07;0;0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

## Below approach might help you

1. **`Case class to generate schema`**

```scala
case class Sales (Name: String, Platform: String, Year: Int, Genre: String, Publisher: String,
NA_Sales: Double, EU_Sales: Double, JP_Sales: Double, Other_Sales: Double)
```

2. **`Read the data`**

```scala
 val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection

    val data =
      """
        |Gran Turismo 3: A-Spec;PS2;2001;Racing;Sony Computer Entertainment;6.85;5.09;1.87;1.16
        |Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3;X360;2011;Shooter;Activision;9.03;4.28;0.13;1.32
        |Pokemon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition;GB;1998;Role-Playing;Nintendo;5.89;5.04;3.12;0.59
        |Call of Duty: Black Ops;X360;2010;Shooter;Activision;9.67;3.73;0.11;1.13
        |Pokemon HeartGold/Pokemon SoulSilver;DS;2009;Action;Nintendo;4.4;2.77;3.96;0.77
        |High Heat Major League Baseball 2003;PS2;2002;Sports;3DO;0.18;0.14;0;0.05
        |Panzer Dragoon;SAT;1995;Shooter;Sega;0;0;0.37;0
        |Corvette;GBA;2003;Racing;TDK Mediactive;0.2;0.07;0;0.01
      """.stripMargin

    val ds = spark.read
      .schema(ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Sales].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType])
      .option("sep", ";")
      .csv(data.split("\n").toSeq.toDS())

    ds.show(false)
    ds.printSchema()
```

Result

```
+---------------------------------------+--------+----+------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|Name                                   |Platform|Year|Genre       |Publisher                  |NA_Sales|EU_Sales|JP_Sales|Other_Sales|
+---------------------------------------+--------+----+------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|Gran Turismo 3: A-Spec                 |PS2     |2001|Racing      |Sony Computer Entertainment|6.85    |5.09    |1.87    |1.16       |
|Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3         |X360    |2011|Shooter     |Activision                 |9.03    |4.28    |0.13    |1.32       |
|Pokemon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition|GB      |1998|Role-Playing|Nintendo                   |5.89    |5.04    |3.12    |0.59       |
|Call of Duty: Black Ops                |X360    |2010|Shooter     |Activision                 |9.67    |3.73    |0.11    |1.13       |
|Pokemon HeartGold/Pokemon SoulSilver   |DS      |2009|Action      |Nintendo                   |4.4     |2.77    |3.96    |0.77       |
|High Heat Major League Baseball 2003   |PS2     |2002|Sports      |3DO                        |0.18    |0.14    |0.0     |0.05       |
|Panzer Dragoon                         |SAT     |1995|Shooter     |Sega                       |0.0     |0.0     |0.37    |0.0        |
|Corvette                               |GBA     |2003|Racing      |TDK Mediactive             |0.2     |0.07    |0.0     |0.01       |
+---------------------------------------+--------+----+------------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+

root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Platform: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Genre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Publisher: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NA_Sales: double (nullable = false)
 |-- EU_Sales: double (nullable = false)
 |-- JP_Sales: double (nullable = false)
 |-- Other_Sales: double (nullable = false)
```

3. **`Get Lowest and highest selling genre`**

```
  // global sales
    val processedDF = ds.withColumn("global_sale", col("NA_Sales") + col("EU_Sales") + col("JP_Sales"))
      .groupBy("Genre")
      .agg(sum("global_sale").as("global_sale_by_genre"))

    println("Lowest selling :: " + processedDF.orderBy(col("global_sale_by_genre").asc).head()
      .getValuesMap(Seq("Genre", "global_sale_by_genre")).mkString(", "))
    println("Highest selling :: " + processedDF.orderBy(col("global_sale_by_genre").desc).head()
      .getValuesMap(Seq("Genre", "global_sale_by_genre")).mkString(", "))
```

RESULT

```
Lowest selling :: Genre -> Sports, global_sale_by_genre -> 0.32
Highest selling :: Genre -> Shooter, global_sale_by_genre -> 27.32
```