# Add columns in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to add multiple columns (`Int` values) to find the highest and lowest selling genre based on global sales.

Format of the table:
**Name**  , **Platform** ,   **Year** ,**Genre** ,**Publisher** ,**NA_Sales** , **EU_Sales** , **JP_Sales** , **Other_Sales**

example data set :
( **Formula** ) [Global Sales = NA_Sales + EU_Sales + JP_Sales]

example output :

Highest selling Genre: Shooter Global Sale (in millions): 27.57

Lowest selling Genre: Strategy Global Sale (in millions): 0.23

```
val vgdataLines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/t1/vgsales-small.csv")
val vgdata = vgdataLines.map(_.split(";"))

val GlobalSales  = vgdata.map(r => r(3), r(5) + r(6) + r(7)). reduceByKey(_+_)
```

What I am trying to use here is a reduce by key to reduce the total `NA_Sales + EU_Sales + JP_Sales` to one value and then reduce by Genre. I created `GlobalSales` with Genre and total sales. But `r(5) + r(6) + r(7)` adds the values into a string.

```
Array[String] = Array(6.855.091.87, 9.034.280.13, 5.895.043.12, 9.673.730.11, 4.42.773.96, 0.180.140, 000.37, 0.20.070, 0.140.320.22, 0.140.110, 0.090.010.15
, 0.020.020.22, 0.140.110, 0.10.130, 0.140.110, 0.110.030, 0.130.020, 0.090.030, 0.060.040, 0.1200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data from [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932350/4758823) here- (I believe both the questions are using the same dataset)

Post splitting the data using `;`, you get the `Array[String]` and when you add that while creating `tuple`, it will append these numbers. you can convert these string to **`Double`** while creating tuple.

### Code

```scala
    val data =
      """Gran Turismo 3: A-Spec;PS2;2001;Racing;Sony Computer Entertainment;6.85;5.09;1.87;1.16
        |Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3;X360;2011;Shooter;Activision;9.03;4.28;0.13;1.32
        |Pokemon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition;GB;1998;Role-Playing;Nintendo;5.89;5.04;3.12;0.59
        |Call of Duty: Black Ops;X360;2010;Shooter;Activision;9.67;3.73;0.11;1.13
        |Pokemon HeartGold/Pokemon SoulSilver;DS;2009;Action;Nintendo;4.4;2.77;3.96;0.77
        |High Heat Major League Baseball 2003;PS2;2002;Sports;3DO;0.18;0.14;0;0.05
        |Panzer Dragoon;SAT;1995;Shooter;Sega;0;0;0.37;0
        |Corvette;GBA;2003;Racing;TDK Mediactive;0.2;0.07;0;0.01""".stripMargin

    val vgdataLines = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(data.split("\n").toSeq)
    val vgdata = vgdataLines.map(_.split(";"))

    val GlobalSales  = vgdata.map(r => (r(3), r(5).toDouble + r(6).toDouble + r(7).toDouble)). reduceByKey(_+_)

    GlobalSales.foreach(println)
```

Output-

```
(Shooter,27.32)
(Role-Playing,14.05)
(Sports,0.32)
(Action,11.129999999999999)
(Racing,14.079999999999998)
```

### Update-1 as per the ask in comments

```scala
 println("### min-max ###")
    val minSale = GlobalSales.min()(Ordering.by(_._2))
    val maxSale = GlobalSales.max()(Ordering.by(_._2))
    println(s"Highest selling Genre: '${maxSale._1}' Global Sale (in millions): '${maxSale._2}'.")
    println(s"Lowest selling Genre: '${minSale._1}' Global Sale (in millions): '${minSale._2}'.")
```

Output-

```
### min-max ###
Highest selling Genre: 'Shooter' Global Sale (in millions): '27.32'.
Lowest selling Genre: 'Sports' Global Sale (in millions): '0.32'.
```

**Some Explaination-**

- `GlobalSales` is a `RDD[Tuple2[String, Double]`. while doing `max` and `min` on the tuple it usually order in sequence i.e. compare the first value and then second. In your usecase , you directly want to collect max on the second element of tuple(global sale in ton), Therefore to override 
  the default behaviour of sorting of tuple, we are using this `Ordering.by(_._2)`

Comment: yeah thanks.I used following code: ```val GlobalSales  = vgdata.map(r =>  (r(3), r(5).toDouble + r(6).toDouble + r(7).toDouble)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val maxsales = GlobalSales.sortBy(_._2, false).take(1)
val minsales = GlobalSales.sortBy(_._2, true).take(1)  ```                                                                                                                                                                                        However, I am trying to print output in format: Highest selling Genre: 'Shooter' Global Sale (in millions): '27.57'. How do I concatenate using println()

Comment: Can you tell me the format? Anyway you can change format, no?

Comment: please see the last comment

Comment: Thanks It works. However would still like to know about                                                                       val minSale = GlobalSales.min()(Ordering.by(_._2))
    val maxSale = GlobalSales.max()(Ordering.by(_._2))// What is _._2?